# food delivery dapp: handling driver assignment to nearest restaurant and within limited distances

Tags: solidity, dapps

I want to use Matic to do this. Is there a good way to assign a driver based on distance to restaurant location? Also I want to limit the amount of distance from restaurant to customer, I don't want people ordering from far away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but that doesn't sound like a very good use case for blockchains. Blockchains are quite bad with external data, they work the best when they don't need data from external sources. And they are not good for lots of computations, such as your distance calculations.

I strongly recommend you to look for more traditional approaches to your problem, such as a centralized server which manages all of that logic.